# Grep: Return a user message when no hits

Tags: bash, find, grep

I have ASCII files to parse that 48  hours old or more ; I can identify them like so

```
find . -name "FILE*TXT"  -mtime +1 -exec ls -ltas '{}' ';'
```

Some files have a list of hardware errors (we test electronic components), some have none. If the file name has no errors, I still want to display a message like so

```
    grep ^err R*VER && echo "No error"
FILEA.TXT:err   ->USB   3910    err 
FILED.TXT:err No Error
```

This grep statement works but it seemingly overrides the find() statement above if I run both at the same time... How can I combine the two statements to create a report that lists the filename and error(s) like so

```
FILEA.TXT Button    3320    err
FILEB.TXT USB   3235    err
FILEC.TXT IR Remote 2436    err
FILED.TXT No error
```

Is it possible to return "No error" with the file name without error? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend came up with this

```
find . -name "FILE*TXT" -mtime +1 -exec sh -c 'grep -H ^err "{}" || echo "{}:No error"' \;
```

I could not figure out how to run grep for each file ; his solution does exactly that.

Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 6):

The `-exec` predicate returns false if the command returns failure.

```
find ... \( -exec grep ... {} \; -o -printf "%p No error\n" \) ...
```